# Laravel show images outside root folder

Tags: php, laravel, image

I am running a Laravel website on local machine.
my laravel is in folder:
/Username/bigproject/laravel-project

In the views of my Laravel app there are  tags which should show files from 
/Username/bigproject/images folder (so it's outiside laravel root folder). How can I form the url in the src so this images are displayed?

`<img src="/Username/bigproject/images/image1.jpg">` doesn't work, of course.

I've played with disks storages from https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem but had no results.

PS. This project is actually for local use only.

Comment: best option move the files, 2nd best symlink

Comment: I've just created symlink "ln -s /Username/bigproject/images /Username/bigproject/larave-project/public" but it doesn't work...(((

Comment: can you browse /Username/bigproject/larave-project/public ? whats the file permissions set to ?

Comment: You can serve them from/through PHP if it has access to the files.  I once built a site that each user has a Zip for their images and they were served directly from the zip using PHP.  cough cough .. it was a mail order bride site ... lol ... the main reason for that was to prevent linking the images from other sites (it was behind a pay wall)

Comment: @IdontDownVote http://joxi.ru/gmv1kdWULDDJdr it says for Username is "read & write" for others (staff & everyone) only "read"

Comment: @IdontDownVote hi man, you were right. simlink works))) i just made a mistake in the <img src="..."> path itself! Would you post an answer?

Comment: done, glad it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the web server cant access files out side of its root, you can create a symbolic link so the files can be in two locations at once.

```
ln -s /Username/bigproject/images /Username/bigproject/larave-project/public
```

thus allowing the web-server (ultimately the browser) to use the access the files with `<img src="/catPic.jpg">`

Comment: in my own project, link <img src="images/catPic.jpg"> worked:) so probably you should change it in your answer

Comment: Fantastic solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If project is for local use only and assuming image are in server root or any folder inside server root (like htdocs, html, public_html, etc) the best option would be to form img tag like

```
src="127.0.0.1/bigproject/images/image1.jpg"
```

If files are outside the webroot / servers root you can access them like

```
file:///c:/Users/Bigproject/images/image1.jpg
```

Comment: wont work, files still have to be inside the webroot for the server to see them

Comment: @IdontDownVote the file:///c:/Users/.. can be used check the edited answer

Answer (score 0):

From top of my head so I might be missing something:

- cd to `myApp/storage`
- run `ln -s /home/me/documents/myFolder myfolder` to create symlink

In `/config/filesystems.php` add to 'disks' array:

```
'mydisk' => 
  [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('storage/myfolder'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/myfolder'
  ]
```

Please let me know if it works or not (was not tested), or correct for typos.

Comment: you wrote it using different file structure. I tried as I understood. it didn't work

Comment: No, of course, use your own file structure. Hmm I'll try it over the weekend and get back.